# Error using dropdown on thymeleaf and spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a form to create a new product. This form has one dropdown with the possibles sizes (setting in the controller) and another dropdown with the possibles brands. I get the brands from the database (I have another independent form to create brands). My problem is that I can't create the product because my dropdowns have some error that I can't find.

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView form(ModelMap map1, ModelMap map2) {
            String[] sizes = new String[] {"S", "M", "L", "XL"};
            List<String> size = Arrays.asList(sizes);
            map1.addAttribute("size", size);

            List<Brand> list = myService.listBrands();
            map2.addAttribute("brands", list);

            return new ModelAndView("formcreate", "product", new Product());
        }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveProduct(@Valid @ModelAttribute("product") Product prod, 
            BindingResult result) throws InstantiationException {

        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("Validation error");
            return "formcreate";
        }else {
            System.out.println("OK");
System.out.println("id brand = " + prod.getBrand().getId());
            System.out.println("name brand = " + prod.getBrand().getName());
            productService.insertProduct(prod);

            return "prodsubmit";
        }
    }
```

formcreate.html:

```
<form th:action="@{/submit}" th:object="${product}" method="post">
          <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />

        <table>

            <tr>
                <td><label>Name </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <div class="dropdown">
                <td><label for="brand.id">Brand</label></td>
                    <td><select class="form-control" id="brand" name="brand">
                        <option th:each="brand : ${brands}"
                                th:value="${brand.id}"
                                th:text="${brand.nombre}"></option>
                    </select></td>
                </div>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label>Preice</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{price}" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <div class="dropdown">

                <td><label for="size">Size</label></td>
                    <td><select class="form-control" id="size" name="size">
                        <option th:each="size : ${size}"
                                th:value="${size}"
                                th:text="${size}"></option>
                    </select></td>
                </div>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Aceptar">

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

In prodsubmit.html I have the code to show the product data.

When I try to create a new product I get the next:

```
id brand = null
name brand = 100
```

Id brand should be 100, and name brand should be Example

Comment: I didn't see you was set `th:field` on `select` tag.  `<select class="form-control" id="brand" name="brand" th:field="SOMETHING">`

Comment: I think I can use id="" name="" instead th:field

Comment: I edit my post with new information because I found another error. Now the code pass the validation but I get an error when I try to insert the content of the dropdown in the database